# Как всегда получать корректное время в конкретном городе (android/ios)?

Tags: java, android, ios, objective-c, время

Пишу приложение на обе платформы, в котором жизненно важно знать текущее точное время в определенном городе, например Новосибирске.

Временная зона недавно сменилась, а так же на зиму и лето переводят часы... Вообщем, оно не постоянно равно GMT+7. Причем надо знать именно корректное время в городе, вне зависимости какое выставлено на устройстве пользователя.

Существуют ли какие-нибудь ресурсы, с которых можно парсить точное время в конкретном городе или же библиотеки с такой функцией...

Вообще, существует какое-либо единственное верное решение в данной ситуации?

(android: знаю как пользоваться Jsoup, парсил время с http://www.epochconverter.com/, но сайт иногда бывает недоступен, а значит этот вариант не подходит)

Буду благодарен любой полезной информации!

Answer (score 1):

Я использовал Google Maps. Через API https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/timezone/json можно получить доступ к актуальной временной зоне по указанным координатам (включая перевод времени). Координаты города легко получить по названию.

Вот документация: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/timezone/intro

Обратите внимание на параметры dstOffset и rawOffset.

Comment: Но в Google Maps ограниченное количество запросов (бесплатных) верно ?

Comment: @kxko Да, 2500 запросов в день. Если нужно больше то платно (но недорого): https://developers.google.com/maps/faq

Answer (score 0):

не берусь гарантировать правильность, но можно поставить тайм зону именно Новосибирск. Может тогда учтет переходы.

```
NSDate *date = [NSDate date];
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [NSDateFormatter new];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/YYYY HH:mm"];

[formatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"Asia/Novosibirsk"]];
NSLog(@"time %@", [formatter stringFromDate:date]);
```